# InfoPath form preview fine but doesn't works on SharePoint

Tags: infopath

I've got a weird issue. When I preview the form on InfoPath the appropriate data appears, but when i publish the form it doesn't get any data, except for the ID. I place the data in text boxes, and set there default values to the appropriate fields in the data connection.

Let me point out that I'm getting the data from the same library I'm publishing too. Don't know if that's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. All I did was republish the form and reselected the fields giving me issues. Whats weird is that they had the same names and everything. Must be a bug.